# Rotate Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a layout and set mu UI element on it what I want to do is to handle touch event and rotate the whole layout

please anyone help

Comment: As I guess rotating the device won't do.. ;) You could just change for a different layout that would be the "rotated" version of your layout. But all devices ain't square.

Answer (score 0):

If by "rotate" you meant "flip", [here](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) is something that can help you.